# ¿Por qué ocupar el metodo Math.floor?

Tags: javascript

A la hora de realizar numeros aleatorios en Javascript, siempre he visto que utilizan el tipico:

```
Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
```

Y de esto me surgieron dudas, **por que se debe multiplicar la diferencia** entre `max y min`? , porque sumarle `1` hace que el **limite maximo sea inclusive**? y ademas por que realizarlo con `Math.floor` y no tan solo hacerlo con `toFixed(0)`, asi seria **más exacto**?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Analicemos la línea:

`Math.random()` devuelve un valor al azar en el rango [0..1), eso significa que si queremos un random entre min y max, tendremos que hacer una serie de transformaciones:

- El rango `[0..1)` tiene un tamaño de 1, pero queremos que sea `[min..max]`, cuyo tamaño es `max - min`, eso explica la multiplicación.
- Además queremos mover el rango desde [0..(max-min)) hasta [min..max), con lo que se le suma min.
- Se usa `Math.floor` porque eso nos asegura un número entero en el rango requerido. `toFixed(n)` redondea, con lo que nos podemos salir de rango si el primer decimal es 5 o superior.
- Como `Math.random()` incluye el 0 pero no el 1, hemos de corregir eso. Si sumamos 1 a la amplitud tenemos un rango de [min, max+1), pero precisamente el haber usado `Math.floor` eliminará cualquier valor por encima de max.

Veamos un ejemplo: con min=2 y max=5:

```js
let a=[];
let min=2, max=5;

for (let i=0;i<30;i++) {
  a.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min +1) + min));
}

console.log(a);
```

Loa valores que obtenemos antes de truncar irán desde 2 hasta 5.99999..., con lo que tenemos siempre valores en el rango deseado y homogéneamente repartidos (siempre que la implementación de `Math.random()` sea buena)

Answer (score 1):

En realidad, al hacer `random`, estamos dividiendo un número entero para que el resultado sea entre el intervalo 0 (inclusivo) y 1 (exclusivo).

Si el programa está compilado en 32 bits, hay que multiplicar el resultado por 2<sup>32</sup>, y si está compilado en 64 bits, se puede multiplicar por 2<sup>52</sup>. Para esto, usamos `Math.pow`, o directamente, el resultado de esa multiplicación.

Sumar 1 es para que en un intervalo, por ejemplo, entre 5 y 10, acepte el 10, es decir que el 10 es inclusivo.

El código para extraer un número aleatorio entre dos números, en realidad debería ser el siguiente. En este caso es entre 5 y 10.

```js
function aleatorio_bits(desde,hasta,bits)
{
  if(bits==64){bits=52}
  return Math.random()*Math.pow(2,bits)%(hasta+1-desde)+desde
}

var desde=5
var hasta=10
console.log("Aleatorio entre 5 y 10.")
for(var i=0;i<5;i++)
{
  console.log(
         "32 bits: "+aleatorio_bits(desde,hasta,32)
    +", \t64 bits: "+aleatorio_bits(desde,hasta,64)
  )
}
```